# When returning a boolean, why use "!!"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boolean

I saw some C++ code like this:

```
bool MyProject::boo(...)
{
  bool fBar = FALSE;
  ....
  return !!fBar;
}
```

I couldn't think of any difference between returning `fBar` directly in this case and returning `!!fBar`. How two negatives make a difference?

Thank you

Comment: It is exactly equivalent to `return fBar;` and serves no purpose but to confuse.

Comment: change `fBar` to any integral type. (`int`, `char`, etc..). Now consider the language and how `!!intVar` is different than `intVar`. Your example is pointless. The real practice as I described is not uncommon. Judging by your rvalue (`FALSE`) you're seeing this code on Windows, where `BOOL` is an `int` and engineers frequently use this practice to squelch compiler warnings.

Comment: Specifically, it's common on Windows to avoid the warning described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6801kcy%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Was it really `bool fBar = FALSE` and not, say, `BOOL fBar = FALSE`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example, there's no difference between returning `fBar` and returning `!!fBar`.

In other cases, e.g. when a user-defined type such as `BOOL` (`typedef`-ed to be `int`) is used, the `!!` construct has the effect of coercing any non-zero value to `true`; i.e. `!!fBar` is equivalent to `fBar ? true : false`. This can make a difference if `fBar` can be 5 and you want to compare it against `TRUE`, which is defined to be `(BOOL)1`.

Comment: It is equivalent to `(int)(fBar ? 1: 0)`, last time I checked. First `!` converts result from integer to bool and negates it. Second `!` negates it again. However, at this point you have a result of type `bool` which you're trying to assign to non-boolean variable. So `bool` is promoted to integer type. `bool` can be either `true` or `false`. `true` becomes 1 when promoted, `false` becomes 0. However, values of `true`/`false` are unknown.

Comment: "!! construct has the effect of coercing any non-zero value to 1; i.e. !!fBar is equivalent to fBar ? 1 : 0" - all wrong... `!` is a boolean operator, so - whether there're one or two of them - always returns either `true` or `false` and never `1` or `0`.  If anything, `!!fBar` is akin to `bool(fBar)`.

Answer (score 3):

This is typically done to avoid compiler warnings in situations when a non-bool value has to be converted to `bool` type. Some compilers (like MSVC++) issue a "performance" warning when a non-bool value is implicitly converted to `bool`. One way to suppress this warning is to use an explicit conversion. Another way is to use the `!!` combination.

However, in your case the argument of `return` is already declared as a `bool`, meaning that the above reasoning does not apply. (Are you sure it was `bool` and not, say, `BOOL`?). In that case there's no meaningful explanation for that `!!`.

Answer (score 0):

`!!` "is" "to boolean" operator (not really, it is two negate operators). It make no different is this case. However, it will make difference if is not `bool`.

e.g.

```
int fBar = 2; // !!fBat evaluate to 1
bool b = (fBar == true) // this is false
b = fBar; // this is true
b = !!fBar; // this is also true

typedef int MyBool; // say some library use int as boolean type
#define MY_TRUE 1
#define MY_FALSE 0
MyBool b2 = fBar; // this evaluate to true, but not equal to true
if (b2 == MY_TRUE )
{
   // this code will not run, unexpected
}
if (b2)
{
   // this code will run
}

MyBool b3 = !!fBar;
if (b2 == MY_TRUE )
{
   // this code will run
}
if (b2)
{
   // this code will run
}
```

Comment: There's no "to boolean" operator `!!`. Don't post stuff that can confuse people.

Comment: `b = !!fBar; // this is true`: sure. But `b = fBar;` also sets `b` to `true`.

Comment: @PeteBecker yes. but it will be wrong if you are _not_ using `bool` (`BOOL` or `int`). at least it may cause unexpected behaviour in `C`

Comment: @BryanChen - sure, if the code was different, the answer might be different. But it's not, so it isn't.

Comment: @PeteBecker ok. I did said it make no different is this case.

Comment: @BryanChen - then I don't understand your "e.g.". I thought your code was supposed to be an example of applying `!!` to something that isn't a `bool`, and my point is that it's not needed there, either.

Comment: @PeteBecker ok. more useful example added

Comment: Another way to deal with multiple values that represent true is to not test for true (and not define a value with a name that's any variant of true). Write conditionals that test for false.